# Are eggs good or bad for iron incorporation?

Tags: diet, micronutrients, iron

Apart from the fact that egg yolk contains very good and plenty of iron, I read on several websites that egg white hinders the digestion of iron. However, I could not find any deeper reasoning about this.

Does egg white lessen the nutritional value of iron in eggs and if yes how strongly? Is it recommended for people suffering from iron deficiency too leave the egg white away when eating eggs?